# How to keep a web application in memory so it can load faster on a first hit

Tags: iis, iis-8, application-pool

I want to prevent loading the web application every time a user hits the web site - for example, after it was not active for some time (the web application terminates)

I saw I can [change the Idle Time-out Action in IIS to "Suspend"](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/idle-worker-process-page-out-in-iis85)

**What is a good way to achieve that?** (any benefits for doing it through code?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for StartMode of the IIS app pool being set to "AlwaysRunning" in the applicationhost.config file. Here's the instructions (pulled from http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2009/10/11/iis-7-5-and-always-running-web-applications.aspx).

To setup the pool set the attribute startMode to AlwaysRunning of the IIS config file C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config:

```
<applicationPools>
    <add name="MyAppWorkerProcess" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning" />
</applicationPools>
```

In the same file, set the AutoStartEnabled to true:

```
<sites> 
     <site name="SomeSite" id="1"> 
          <application path="/" serviceAutoStartEnabled="true" />
     </site>
</sites>
```

Alternatively, you can do this through the IIS interface. Open IIS, click on the Server icon in the left column, then click on the Configuration Editor icon under Management. From the Section dropdown, choose system.applicationHost/applicationPools. There will be a Collection entry there with a Count of all your app pools. Click the little ellipses in the Count which will open a window with all your pools listed. Find your app pool in the list, make sure AutoStart is true and startMode is AlwaysRunning. Restart IIS and you'll be good to go.

Check Task Manager on the details tab, it will show you the w3wp.exe processes and the name of the app pool in the User name column. This is how you can check to make sure it is running.

Comment: You answer is interesting, I didn't know about this startMode option, but I'm still trying to understand the difference between that and using "Suspend"  as suggested at the bottom of this blog page: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2013/06/25/whats-new-in-iis-8-5-microsoft-internet-information-services-8-5-new-features/

Comment: Hmm seems similar, although it seems more centered around the idle timeout rather than initial start. The way I described, the app pool will always be running even if no one has actually visited the site.

Answer (score 0):

One old school (read: reliable, simple) way to do this is to write a CRON job, scheduled task or service to make a request to the application every x minutes (where x is less than the idle time-out).